# Why won't the Gmail API send email messages as HTML from C#?

Tags: c#, api, gmail

I am trying to use the Gmail API to send a HTML email from C#. The email gets sent but Gmail refuses to acknowledge that it should be an HTML email.

This is the code I am using:

```
var template = @"from: {1}{4}to: {0}{4}subject: {2}{4}MIME-Version: 1.0{4}Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8{4}Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64{4}{4}{3}";
body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
var result = string.Format(template, to, from, subject, body, "\r\n");
result = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

var gMessage = new Message()
{
    Raw = result
};
service.Users.Messages.Send(gMessage, "me").Execute();
```

This is what the result string looks like before encoding to base64:

```
from: test@test.com
to: test@test2.com
subject: testSubject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

&amp;lt;html&amp;gt;&amp;lt;head&amp;gt;

&amp;lt;title&amp;gt;Push Email&amp;lt;/title&amp;gt;   

&amp;lt;/head&amp;gt;    
&amp;lt;body&amp;gt; blah  

&amp;lt;/body&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/html&amp;gt;
```

(The app actually uses real email addresses which I have replaced with "test@..." in the above example for privacy.)

I tried every possible combination of header arrangement, content-transfer-encoding (base64, 7bit, 8bit, etc), content-type charset (ascii, utf8, etc), I tried using UrlEncode instead of HtmlEncode but the email body is either just displayed as unrendered HTML or it is displayed as an encoded url string (depending on whether I use html encode or url encode and what contet transfer encoding I specify).

The point is, the mail is working, the body is being sent but it just stubbornly refuses to render the HTML. I either get this:

```
<html><head> <title>Push Email</title> </head> <body> blah </body></html>
```

Or this:

```
%3chtml%3e%3chead%3e%0d%0a%0d%0a%3ctitle%3ePush+Email%3c%2ftitle%3e+++%0d%0a+%0d%0a%3c%2fhead%3e++++%0d%0a%3cbody%3e+blah++%0d%0a++++%0d%0a%3c%2fbody%3e%3c%2fhtml%3e
```

Or this:

```
&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;Push Email&lt;/title&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; blah &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
```

I would just send an SMTP email but, probably for security, Google won't allow it if you have 2 factor auth for the account (which I have and don't plan on disabling).

Also, I am just building my MIME message as a regular string. This may have something to do with it but I don't know. I don't plan on using any third party nuget packages / libraries such as MimeKit. I just want a C# solution only.

Finally, I need to be able to send HTML emails so that I may send links as per my app business logic.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried replace the symbol names in the `result` string by the actual symbol? i.e. , replace `&amp;lt;html&amp;gt;&amp;lt;head&amp;gt;` by `<html><head>`

Comment: What happens if you comment out `body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);`?

Comment: @Magnetron: The symbol names (&amp;lt, etc) are there because of the fact that I escape the whole html using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode call. I also tried with UrlEncodde. If I leave the string unescaped, the API returns Error 400 "Invalid ByteString"..

Comment: @mjwills: the Gmail API returns 400 Invalid ByteString if I comment it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. First of all, the body of the mail must not be escaped but the whole MIME string should. But, as mentioned previously, if I leave the body unencoded the API complains about an invalid byte string.

The problem is that the resulting base64 string should be encoded in a URL safe manner. The python code on the [Gmail API guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) uses a method called `urlsafe_b64encode` which is different from the normal base 64 method in that the resulting string is URL safe.

I thought I could replicate this in C# using HTML or URL encoding and then using the standard `Convert.ToBase64String` method to convert the MIME string to base64 but I was wrong. After searching the MSDN website I finally found the [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode(v=vs.110).aspx) method which does just what the `urlsafe_b64encode` python method does which is to encode the string in a URL safe variant and also convert it to base64. The final code thus becomes:

```
// Template for the MIME message string (with text/html content type)
var template = @"from: {1}{4}to: {0}{4}subject: {2}{4}MIME-Version: 1.0{4}Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8{4}Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64{4}{4}{3}";
// Fill in MIME message fields
var result = string.Format(template, to, from, subject, body, "\r\n");
// Get the bytes from the string and convert it to a URL safe base64 string
result = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

// Instantiate a Gmail API message and assign it the encoded MIME message
var gMessage = new Message()
{
    Raw = result
};
// Use the Gmail API Service to send the email
service.Users.Messages.Send(gMessage, "me").Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body looks like passed by HtmlEncode twice, i.e. `<` once passed become `&lt;` twice passed become `&amp;lt;` which is what you have. As you didn't posted the original code from where `body` is being setted before the enconding, all I can say is you have to have this as your `result` string before enconding to base64:

```html
from: test@test.com
to: test@test2.com
subject: testSubject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<html><head>

<title>Push Email</title>   

</head>    
<body> blah  

</body></html>
```

To get this, you can replace this line

```
body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
```

by this

```
body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(body);
```

Comment: The content of the body string is identical to the HTML you posted. If I leave the HTML as is inside the MIME message, the API complains about an invalid bytestring. That is why I escape it with HtmlEncode (I also tried with UrlEncode).

Answer (score 0):

Really just need the option "IsBodyHtml=true":

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html = "<html><head><body><h1>hello world!</h1></body><head></html>";
            var from = "me@here.com";
            var to = "them@there.com";

            var msg = new MailMessage(from, to)
            {
                Subject = "My Subject",
                Body = html,
                IsBodyHtml = true
            };
            SendGmail("myUserName", "myPassword", msg);
        }

        public static void SendGmail(string username, string password, MailMessage msg)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            client.Send(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as I've said, using SMTP isn't an option since google doesn't allow SMTP when you are using 2 factor authentication for that account (i.e.: when it sends you an SMS verification code when you log in)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @user1969903 give the direction, but i'm using .Net6, this work for me

```
// Template for the MIME message string (with text/html content type)
var mimeString = $"from: {from@gmail.com}\r\n" +
                 $"to: {to@gmail.com}\r\n" +
                 $"subject: Test Edm\r\n" +
                 $"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" +
                 $"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n" +
                 $"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" +
                 $"{html_here}";

var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mimeString);

var gMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message()
{
    Raw = Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes).Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "")
};

service.Users.Messages.Send(gMessage, "me").Execute();
```